# Parsing or changing the date format with javascript

Tags: javascript, date, parsing, format

I'm trying to change the date format for some data coming in. I can change it to this format "02-10" but i wanted it to look like this "Feb 10 2015"

So far i have something like this that changes it to each day of the week, but i would like to change that. Here's what i have.

```
$scope.hourlyData = [];  
        var hourData = [];
        var hourItem = [];
        var dailyData = [];
        var day;
        var date;
        var Everymonth = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];

        var item = ['Day', 'Number of Interactions', {role: 'style'}];
        dailyData.push(item);

        var dailyReports = $scope.tweetReports.dailyReports;
        $scope.numberOfdailyReports = dailyReports.length;


        for (var i = 0; i < dailyReports.length; i++) {
          if (dailyReports[i] != null) {
            //console.log("Tweets on " + dailyReports[i].day + ":" + dailyReports[i].tweets);
            day = dailyReports[i].day.split(" ")[0];
            date = dailyReports[i].day.split(" ")[1];
            date = date.substr(date.indexOf('-') + 1);

            if (numDays =< 7) {
              day = day.toLowerCase();
              day = day.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + day.substr(1);
            } else {
              day = date;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to use libraries, You can use [momentJS](http://momentjs.com/) like this 
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HKhw8/1011/)

```
var dateString = "2013-07-18";
var date = moment(dateString).format('MMM DD YYYY');
```